# fetching data from datastore without refresh the page

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there any good way to fetch the data from the datastroe in app engine without refreshing the whole page , like twitter when new tweets come , or facebook like when comments or status appears

Thanks

Comment: [Ajax](http://www.google.com/search?q=ajax)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about asynchronous notifications, where the server notifies the client when new data is available. This can be done on App Engine by using the [Channel API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/).

Comment: +1 for a good specific resource in this particular perceived use case.

Comment: I am implemnting something looks like [this](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/worldview/demo/) so I have the coordinates I have the messages in the datastore I want to show the message when someone post it without refresh

Comment: @Salah Then the Channel API is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use [AJAX](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/rpc.html).

Comment: I cant use web socket in app engine ?

Comment: I will check it , thanks 
I saw people using something called http://pusher.com
and http://www.nodejs.com